# treeview control in asp.net very slow to load nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my asp.net webpage, the treeview control has thousands of nodes and the tree is very slow to load. The nodes data is coming from sql database using the code below. What can we do to optimize or improve the performance.

```
public partial class TaxonomyAllTermsTree : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.AddNodes(this.TreeView1.Nodes, 0, this.LoadData());
        TreeView1.CollapseAll();
    }

  }


  private void AddNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int level, System.Data.DataTable dt)
  {
    string filterExp = string.Format("ParentID='{0}'", level);
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow r in dt.Select(filterExp))
    {
        TreeNode item = new TreeNode()
        {
            Text = r[2].ToString(),
            Value = r[1].ToString(),
            NavigateUrl = "SomeURL.aspx?TermID=" + r[0].ToString()
        };
        this.AddNodes(item.ChildNodes, int.Parse(r[0].ToString()), dt);
        nodes.Add(item);
    }
  }

  private System.Data.DataTable LoadData()
  {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ThesaurusConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetFullTree", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If there is a lot of data, the browser is going to take its time to render all of that in the treeview. I would strongly suggest you find a different approach to this, especially because it seems like you are not doing any postbacks with the nodes in this treeview, but just something with the Urls. Google some Async treeviews: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/treeview/treeview_suppliment.htm

Comment: Comment the line TreeView1.CollapseAll() and then see whether the tree loads up faster?

Comment: Removing the CollapseAll does load the tree quicker than before but I dont want to show the user all the nodes on the page load.

Comment: Yeah. Is there a massive speed difference or minor? Because if it is massive then it's the tree collapse and expand that is causing performance degrade.

Comment: I guess the tree is loading now in half the time it was loading before so this is noticeable

Comment: Ok. Can you change the treeview design property ExpandDepth to 0 and then fiddle around that area. Because I guess it's related to the expand and collapse of the tree. and I know its annoying :(

Comment: Also your stored procedure GetFullTree ... what does that do?

Comment: Great stuff Azhar. The performance has definitely improved by the two changes you suggested. The stored procedure returns three columns TermID, Name, ParentID

Comment: is there a way we can cache the stored procedure so that there are no trips to sql server every time the page is loaded

Comment: You could cache the stored procedure result, that being the DataTable. It could be done in a way it would only grab the results from the stored procedure when the user first enters the page. The result would be reused afterwards. The user won't be seeing live data tho.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** As mentioned by @Azhar set [ExpandDepth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.expanddepth%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to 0

`ExpandDepth` -  gets or sets the number of levels that are expanded when a TreeView control is displayed for the first time.

**2)** Use ASP.NET caching to store the DataTable in cache for a certain period of time to avoid unnecessary database trips, which will most definitely improve performance.

Here are some helpful articles about caching:

1. [How to Add items to the Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [How to Delete items from the Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edfcywt6%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And here's an example

```
//The item will be in the cache for 10 minutes
DataTable table = LoadData();
Cache.Insert("TreeView", table, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10), TimeSpan.Zero);
```

Check if the key exists in Cache, if it does load the data from the cache, otherwise load the data from a db and insert it into the Cache:

```
if (Cache["TreeView"] != null)
{
    var table = Cache["TreeView"] as DataTable;
    //Do something with the DataTable
}
else
{
    DataTable table = LoadData();
    Cache.Insert("TreeView", table, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1), TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

Hope these example help you!